# Folder for Windows 10 Admin not shown under users

Tags: windows-10

I am the admin on my laptop. Today, Windows 10 just updated itself to the latest version. On a whim, I happened to also rename my PC today. Instead of a long string of letters provided by the manufacturer, I changed it to a name recognizable to me.

Upon restarting the computer, everything has gone haywire.

First, all of my OneDrive files were gone.
Second, I noticed that one program that had been installed (Visual Studio Code), was simply missing. I can't find it in the program files. This was not installed today but ages ago.
Lastly, I noticed that while I am infact logged on as the admin, i no longer see my account in the file directory under "users".

Any ideas why this might be and **how I can get it back?**

What I have done thus far:

- using the cmd window, I checked that my account is still there (`net users`)... ok
- tried logging off and logging on... only to discover that i didn't have the option to 'log off'
- in an effort to go back to the previous state, i changed the computer name back to what it was previously.

**UPDATE**
Based on the suggestion of JW0914's comment, I attempted to go to `%AppDataLocal%` only to get an error message saying

> Windows can't find %AppDataLocal%. Check the spelling and try again.

The other paths did worked (`%AppData%`, `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`)

When I went to `%AppData%` I saw only one folder named Microsoft. Nothing else! I then realized that folder were hidden, by using View in the File Explorer menu and checking the Hidden Items checkbox.

Thus, it seems that in the update process various setting i had, were not correctly implemented/restored. I now have all my files back, even from OneDrive.

The only thing missing at this point is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: "i didn't have the option to 'log off'" -- what options did you have? In PowerShell/cmd, What does `whoami` return? This sounds somewhat like a "temporary Profile" issue -- are there any folders under ``c:\Users`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to sign in to your account. To sign-out of your current account in Windows 10 do the following. Open the Start menu. Right-click on the top most icon on the left-hand side of the start menu. It is the icon for the profile picture of the account. Once you right click on it, it will give you a menu with three options: Change account settings, Lock, and Sign Out. If you press sign-out it will take you to the sign-in screen. From there you can select other accounts in the bottom left. If they are not there you can enable username sign-in using netplwiz.

Comment: under "c:\users" i only see *Public* ... i can go to my old account by typing in my username, but the folder is  shown as empty

Comment: @iskyfire I just signed out and did what you suggested. I had two accounts there. One my own and another new one that i've never seen before "Administrator"... yet, it is my own account that is actually listed as the administrator  account in Settings>Your info

Comment: The "Administrator" account, which i just logged in to, is seemingly nothing more than a regular user account... in fact i had to click through the setup screens in order to finish.

Comment: When Windows updates, it sometimes leaves a windows.old folder, do you have a windows.old folder at C:\? If so, there may be a users folder inside that contains the previous directory structure.

Comment: @iskyfire saddly nothing to be seen like that. I assume in the user folder? if so, nothing there.

Comment: @rohrl77 Correlation doesn't equal causation - renaming of the PC has nothing to do with this. The Administrator user is the built-in Admin account & should always remain disabled; Once you disable the account _(`net user administrator /active:no`)_, remove the Administrator user folder. Windows version updates never delete files, as any files removed from the old version are always placed in `C:\Windows.old`... it sounds like the update was interrupted before it could fully finish the Audit pass.  Also, VS Code gets installed to `%AppDataLocal%`, not `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you for your comment. I turned off the admin account using your suggestion. And very insightful about where VS Code gets installed... boggles me why they put it there, but i guess there will be a reason. "Correlation doesn't equal causation" - true, but that is something you need to first discover, and since it was one of the things i changed, it was a likely candidate. In anycase, the OneDrive does seem to have some linke to the computer name, as that is also stored in the cloud. I'll change the computer name again later... see whether it has an impact at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seems to have gone baddly in the update process. Thanks to JW0914 I figured out that files were hidden, which should have been visible to me (at least based upon my last settings). Upon making the visible again using `folder preferences>uncheck hidden` I was able to reactivate everything (given that it was actually just hidden).

Interestingly, programs like visual studio code which are apperantly under AppData, were also hidden in the menus and unhiding them in the folder made them visible in the menu as well!

Comment: VS Code, as well as other software, is installed into either `%AppData%` or `%AppDataLocal%` for a few reasons.  I suspect the main reason is that it allows each user to have their own extensions installed, but it also allows the software to update without requiring Admin privileges _(this is the actual reason why Atom is installed there, in lieu of `%ProgramFiles%`)_.

Comment: As to the update, you may want to do a repair install, which is essentially what the bi-annual updates are.  [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) the most current Windows install ISO _(choose to install Windows on another PC so the Media Creation Tool saves the ISO)_ from Microsoft, extract the content of the ISO to a folder and, _while still booted to Windows_, run `setup.exe`, choosing to Keep All Files and Settings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! And your help. Now i'm on to the next (original) problem... PIP does not work for me in the cmd line.

Comment: Verify that PATH still contains its file location: `sysdm.cpl` > Advanced > Environment Variables... > System Variables > PATH

Comment: It did not... i just added `C:\Users\rohrl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts`. It works!!! Thank you!!

Comment: If you want to put your original comment as the answer, i'll gladly mark it as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: No problem at all =] I don't have it installed so I can't verify, but if that path is where the executable is, then that's the correct path to add.  If all of your custom additions to PATH are missing due to the update not fully completing the 7 phases of the Windows Install Process, you can mount the old registry hives in `regedit` _(google how to mount a registry hive)_ that will be at `C:\Windows.old\Windows\System32\config` (System PATH: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` User: `HKCU\Environment`)